# How to disable Jinja2 whitespace trimming after comment?

Tags: whitespace, jinja2, template-engine

I have a Jinja 2 template like this:

```
foo{# comment #}
bar
```

When `trim_blocks` is enabled, the template renders as:

```
foobar
```

I want the template to render like this:

```
foo
bar
```

I tried using the `+#}` syntax to disable trimming after the comment but it didn't work.  How can I do this?  I don't want to have to add an extra line break after every single comment in my template.

**Edit:** I am not in control of the code that renders the template, so any solution must be within the template itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply output a newline using `{{ "\n" }}` after the comment:

```
foo{# comment about foo #}{{ "\n" }}
bar
```

Ideally you could change the rendering code to not strip comments, but if you can't this will preserve the desired *output*.

Answer (score 1):

You can change lexing rules for comment blocks

```
import re

from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2.lexer import TOKEN_COMMENT, TOKEN_COMMENT_BEGIN, TOKEN_COMMENT_END, Failure


env = Environment()
env.trim_blocks = True

c = lambda x: re.compile(x, re.M | re.S)
e = re.escape

comment_block_suffix_re = ''

env.lexer.rules[TOKEN_COMMENT_BEGIN] = [
    (c(r'(.*?)((?:\-%s\s*|%s)%s)' % (
        e(env.comment_end_string),
        e(env.comment_end_string),
        comment_block_suffix_re
    )), (TOKEN_COMMENT, TOKEN_COMMENT_END), '#pop'),
    (c('(.)'), (Failure('Missing end of comment tag'),), None)
]
```

See [source code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/lexer.py#L492) of lexer module for details